# Opening a vcs file in android phonegap

Tags: android, vcalendar, cordova-2.7.0

I am downloading a vcs file from remote server for adding events on calendar in android phonegap..vcs file downloads properly..My problem is it dosent prompts me to open the file..so the user isnt able to load the event automatically..Could any1 suggest me a plugin or any other equivalent code..

PS : I am a newbie to android :)

```
enter code here

<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem.name);
    console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
}
function onDeviceReady(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, null);   
}

function win(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log("read success");
    console.log(evt.target.result);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
};

 var fail = function(evt) {
console.log(error.code); 
};
 function syncCal(){

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(server address);
var filePath =  'file:///sdcard/london3.vcs';
fileTransfer.download(
uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        entry.file(win, fail);
        entry.file.open;
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
)
```

}